# In IE7 two functions not working in window.onload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
window.onload = function () {
  new JsDatePick({
    useMode: 2,
    target: "prod_war",
    dateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d",
  });
  showResult('SHOW', '', '');
};
```

The above functions fail to execute `onload` in Internet Explorer

Comment: When asking a question you should end it with a `?` and it should also contain any error messages you receive ... and then once someone provides a useful answer you should accept it - [If you have no idea how to accept an answer **read this**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170679)

Answer (score 6):

Remove the "extra" comma :

```
window.onload = function () {
  new JsDatePick({
    useMode: 2,
    target: "prod_war",
    dateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d" // comma removed from here
  });
  showResult('SHOW', '', '');
};
```

IE complains about this - other browser tend to ignore it